# How to rename and reorganize file using regex and rename-cli?

Tags: regex, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a large amount of article on my blog I want to rename and reorganize.

The current structure is this one:

```
2005_03_19_this_is_the_filename.md
2007_07_23_another_filename.md
2021_01_12_filename.md
```

And here's what I want to achieve:

```
2005/03/this_is_the_filename/index.md
2007/07/another_filename/inedx.md
2021/01/filename/index.md
```

Here's [the regex I want to use](https://regex101.com/r/F9zU3z/5) but I do not know how to execute it.

```perl
/(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(.*).md/gm
substitution: $1/$2/$4/index.md
```

I'm currently trying to execute it with [rename-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rename-cli) but can't figure out how to write the command.

Comment: Maybe `rename -r "(?<year>\d+)_(?<month>\d+)_\d+_(?<name>.*)\.md" --noindex *.md "{{year}}/{{month}}/{{name}}/index.md"`?

Comment: `rename-cli` appears to be buggy on my OSC. You can use perl `rename` utility as: `rename -n 's~(\d{4})_(\d{2})_\d{2}_(.+)(\.md)$~$1/$2/$3/index.md~' *.md`

Comment: @anubhava Doesn't seem to work. All files are renamed with the same name.

Comment: [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) is worth a look - see the Github wiki for plenty of examples

Comment: Are you using it on Windows, Linux...? Do you consider using any other tools?

Comment: @alienlebarge: I was talking about a different `rename` utility that is perl based not this `rename-cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to it with the following command:

```
$ rename -p 's~(\d{4})_(\d{2})_\d{2}_(.+)(\.md)$~$1/$2/$3/index.md~' *.md
```

Thanks to @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Also use

```bash
rename -p 's,([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_[0-9]{2}_(.*)(?=\.md$),$1/$2/$3/index,' *.md
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/64WU6a/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    md                       'md'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```